# Install Anaconda environment on Google Drive for repeated use or use in multiple Google Colab VMs

Tags: anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory, anaconda3

The problem I was actually trying to solve is to use a permanent way to install conda on google colab rather than doing it every time. But I have been having trouble because of the infamous space problem in the "My Drive" path, which prevents me to install miniconda somewhere on my drive. Hence I am thinking of simply uploading my local files where I have set up anaconda. But how would I do that. Has someone tried it before? Please help.TIA.

Edit: looked at various SO answers but none dealt with it.

Edit2: The actual problem arose when trying to install miniconda permanently somewhere on the drive rather than at the default `/usr/local`. Installer script prevents me from installing into directories with spaces("My Drive").

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "the infamous space problem in "My Drive""? I'm assuming that you're using a personal rather than a G  Suite account (as these have unlimited storage)?

Comment: @rchurt I was actually referring literally to the space between the words "My" and "Drive". For reference have a look at [this](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/8914333?hl=en) . And some of the problems because of it.

Comment: @rchurt added edit. Please see if you can help.

Comment: Ok, let me know if that works for you. I adapted it from something else, so it might have to be tweaked slightly for this specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another potential solution - from an Answer I wrote for this Question:
[How to install conda on Google Drive for Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464195/how-to-install-conda-on-google-drive-for-google-colab/67104989#67104989)

It is based on storing a tarball of the conda installation on Google Drive, then copying this over to Colab when you start or re-run a notebook. It is faster than installing conda and the required packages from scratch each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a symlink to another folder and install it into that:

```
%%shell
install_dir="/gdrive/My Drive"
install_dir_linked="/usr/local"

mkdir -p "$install_dir_linked"
ln -sf "$install_dir" "$install_dir_linked" #create symlink
```