# How to install conda on Google Drive for Google Colab?

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory

```
! wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```

This cell of code installs conda for my Google Colab. Colab has a time limit on its session, which resets the environment state and data after 8 or 9 hours of active calculation so I need to restart this cell again and again.

Is there a way to install conda and all necessary for me packages on Google Drive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but it may be faster than downloading and building a new conda installation every time. Overview of steps:

1. Install conda into a local directory on Colab, tarball this directory and store it on Google Drive.
2. When you start a new Colab notebook or restart an existing one, run a codeblock to fetch the conda install from Google Drive and re-setup the environment.

### 1. Create installation of conda and the packages you need (once only)

Download and install miniconda to `/content/miniconda3` directory:

```
%env PYTHONPATH=
! wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /content/miniconda3
```

Add miniconda to the system `PATH`:

```
import os
path = '/content/miniconda3/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
%env PATH=$path
```

Install the conda packages you need (e.g. packagexyz):

```
!conda install -c conda-forge packagexyz -y
```

Optional codeblock: check packagexyz works correctly. This should print the version of the packagexyz and its location within the conda directory:

```
import sys
_ = sys.path.append("/content/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import packagexyz
print(packagexyz.__version__, packagexyz.__file__)
```

Copy everything over to Google Drive (click the link to fetch the authentication code then paste it into the box):

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!tar -zcf conda_colab.tar.gz /content/miniconda3
!cp conda_colab.tar.gz /content/drive/My\ Drive/
```

### 2. Copy conda back to Colab (run whenever you restart a notebook)

Mount Google Drive (requires auth code input again), copy back the conda installation, and re-setup the environment:

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!tar -xf /content/drive/My\ Drive/conda_colab.tar.gz -C ../

import os
path = '/content/miniconda3/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
%env PATH=$path
%env PYTHONPATH=
import sys
_ = sys.path.append("/content/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
```

#### Notes

- This solution is only lightly tested. You may need to set other environment variables depending on the packages you install.
- Step 2 might be faster by tweaking the `tar` compression settings. If you have a really big conda installation, consider using `apt-get` to install `pigz` at the start of both Step 1 and Step 2, then add `--use-compress-program=pigz` to the `!tar...` commands to parallelize the compress & decompress steps.

Comment: Rather than storing conda installations on Google Drive as per this answer, I now recommend using a `constructor`-based solution with [conda-colab](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab). Check out this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jaimergp/condacolab/blob/main/constructor-example/condacolab_constructor_tutorial.ipynb). It is a cleaner and faster solution than using Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Install Conda in every session:

code cell 1:

```
%%bash
filepath=/tmp/miniconda.sh
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ${filepath}
bash ${filepath} -b -p /opt/conda
rm -f ${filepath}
```

code cell 2:

```
path=%env PATH
%env PATH=/opt/conda/bin:{path}
```